# bash Script Arguments grouping

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopts

I am having problems with expansion of command-line options containing spaces. They are not getting grouped as I expect them to be. How can I modify following code(below) to get the desired output(below).

```
function myFunction {
  while getopts "a:b:A:" optionName; do
    echo "$optionName::$OPTARG"
  done
}

#dynamic variable, cannot be hardcoded into $MY_ARGS
MY_VAR="X1=162356374 X2=432876 X3=342724"

#$MY_ARGS is useful and will be used more than once,
#so we don't want to eliminate it and replace it's usage with its value everywhere
MY_ARGS="-a 24765437643 -b '$MY_VAR' -A jeeywewueuye"

myFunction $MY_ARGS
```

Actual Output:

```
a::24765437643
b::'X1=162356374
```

Desired Output:

```
a::24765437643
b::X1=162356374 X2=432876 X3=342724
A::jeeywewueuye
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to store a list of arguments is in an array. An array can handle arguments with whitespace without problem, and you don't have to figure out how to get the quotes and backslashes *just right*.

```
MY_ARGS=(-a 24765437643 -b "$MY_VAR" -A jeeywewueuye)

myFunction "${MY_ARGS[@]}"
```

The only unnatural part about arrays is the weird syntax to expand them: `"${array[@]}"`. The quotes, curly braces, and `[@]` notation are all important.

Comment: More than just the *best* way, it's the *only* way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that arrays answer the question in the best way.
Perhaps you don't want to use arrays (colleagues will not understand), or you must obey the [Google Guidelines for bash](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml) (nice work, I agree with for over 90%). that claims: "*If you find you need to use arrays for anything more than assignment of ${PIPESTATUS}, you should use Python.* ".
When you must look for another solutions:

An ugly solution is changing the IFS:

```
function myFunction {
  while getopts "a:b:A:" optionName; do
    echo "$optionName::$OPTARG"
  done
}

#dynamic variable, cannot be hardcoded into $MY_ARGS
MY_VAR="X1=162356374 X2=432876 X3=342724"

MY_ARGS="-a/24765437643/-b/"$MY_VAR"/-A/jeeywewueuye"

IFS=/
myFunction ${MY_ARGS}
```

Perhaps you want to do something with myFunction

```
function myFunction {
  while getopts "a:bA:" optionName; do
    case "${optionName}" in
       b) echo "${optionName}::${MY_VAR}" ;;
       *) echo "${optionName}::${OPTARG}" ;;
    esac
  done
}
```

or you could `tr` the spaces into another character before calling myFunction and `tr` the characters back to spaces in `myFunction()`.